# Approach to Map Inbound Web Service Request Fields to a Defined Wrapper Class?

Tags: apex, integration, callout, webservices, design-patterns

We have multiple external systems POSTing callouts to a salesforce custom web service. We need an approach to map the request fields from these external systems to a generic defined wrapper class.

We have an identifier associated with each external system, so essentially we can do the conditional wrapper instantiation. But from the scalability perspective, It won't be a good solution.

Any alternative approach to achieve this? Maybe factory pattern or custom metadata types to store the field mapping in JSON format per external system?